# Retrying a polling service with n seconds delay

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6

```
private pollSubscriptions: Subscription;
private defaultPollTime: number = 2000;
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
) {
    this.pollSubscriptions = new Subscription();
}

pollRequest<T>(
    url: string,
    updateStatus: any,
    pollWhileCondition: Function,
    onPollingSuccessCallback?: Function,
    timer = this.defaultPollTime
) {
    this.pollSubscriptions.add(timer(0, 2000).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.http.get<T>(url).pipe(
            catchError((error: any) => empty()))),
        tap(updateStatus),
        takeWhile(data => pollWhileCondition(data)))
        .subscribe());
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.pollSubscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
```

I am able to poll for multiple urls simultaneously. But how can I enhance current functionality so that I can meet the following requirements:

1. If a url which is polled gets failed then how can we retry that poll url with a delay of 3(n) secs for 3 times?
2. How can we add distinct operator on the urls being polled?

***STILL NO SOLUTION***

Thanks in advance

Comment: STILL NO SOLUTION
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this helps..

A couple of things:

1. You'll probably want to use a shared timer for your polling if you'd like all of your polls to happen at the same time. So I've added a `pollWhen` property below.
2. You're looking for `retryWhen`, it's a pretty tricky operator to understand, but basically it works like this:  When you subscribe, it calls the function you pass it with an observable of potential errors, when an error is emitted, you're expected to scrub that into a "nexted" value to retry, an immediate completion (ex empty) to complete quietly, or an error (ex throwError) to kill the observable with an error.

```js
class Component() {
  /** ticks every 10 seconds */
  pollWhen = timer(0, 10000)
    .pipe(share());

  private pollSubscriptions: Subscription;

  constructor(
      private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
      this.pollSubscriptions = new Subscription();
  }

  pollRequest<T>(
      url: string,
      updateStatus: any,
      pollWhileCondition: Function,
      onPollingSuccessCallback?: Function,
      timer = this.defaultPollTime
  ) {
      this.pollSubscriptions.add(this.pollWhen.pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
        this.http.get<T>(url).pipe(
          // Setup retries
          retryWhen(
            errors => errors.switchMap(
              // if more than 3 retries,
              // stop retrying quietly
              (_, i) => i < 3
                ? timer(1000)
                : EMPTY
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      tap(updateStatus),
      takeWhile(pollWhileCondition)
    ).subscribe());
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.pollSubscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question you can use retryWhen operator and replace catch. 
For 2 question, method needs a bit of rewrite, you can change pollRequest to a subject() to store and emit the distinct url to the stream for processing.

```
    var pollUrl = new rxjs.Subject()
const updateStatus = () => true
const pollWhileCondition = () => true
const http = url => {
  console.log('http call...',url)
  return rxjs.timer(1000).pipe(
  rxjs.operators.tap(()=>{
    throw "http call error"
  })
  )
}
const distinctUrl = pollUrl.pipe(rxjs.operators.distinct())

distinctUrl.pipe(
  rxjs.operators.mergeMap(url =>  {
    return rxjs.timer(0, 2000).pipe(rxjs.operators.map(() => url))
  }),
  rxjs.operators.tap(()=>console.log('xxx')),
  rxjs.operators.mergeMap(url => http(url).pipe(
  rxjs.operators.retry(3),
   )),
    rxjs.operators.catchError(()=>rxjs.empty()),
    rxjs.operators.repeat()
).subscribe(()=>{},err=>{
console.warn(err)
},()=>console.log('comple'))

pollUrl.next('http://google.com')
setTimeout(()=> pollUrl.next('http://twitter.com') ,7000)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cy0nbs3x/1535/

Comment: Great!! How can we restrict the number of times to 3 with above implementation. Can you please elaborate on point solution @Fan Cheung

Comment: updated but braces and brackets are messy, hope you get the idea

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the second part of question?

Comment: which part is confusing you? please also take a look at https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html

Comment: Thanks Fan!!! retryWhen is working!!! I was asking about how can we add distinct operator on the urls being polled?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Fan. Added ur code for retrying but the polling is not getting stopped and I am getting the below console error:
core.js:1671 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'function (source) { return source.lift(new DelayWhenOperator(delayDurationSelector)); }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: it is even retrying after 3 tries. I think max retry reached is not happening.

Comment: I think the reason it is going on retrying even after retry limit is because of :
=> this.pollSubscriptions.add(observableTimer(0, timer).pipe...

Comment: Your use case is pretty complicated. I rewrite your function a bit and i hope you understand the code. I have updated the answer and created a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Not the complete solution but here I am able to achieve retrying 3 times with delay of 3 seconds. I am still seeking for how can I make the active poll urls distinct. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import { timer as observableTimer, Subscription, interval, of, concat, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, tap, take, switchMap, repeat, retryWhen, scan, mapTo, expand, exhaustMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ReportPollingService {

    private pollSubscriptions: Subscription;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    pollRequest<T>(url: string, updateStatus: any, pollWhileCondition: Function){
     if (this.pollSubscriptions.closed) {
       this.pollSubscriptions = new Subscription();// re-open polling
     }
     const request$ = this.http.get<T>(url);
     const firstRequest$ = request$;
     const polling$ = interval(options.interval).pipe(
         take(1),
         exhaustMap(() => request$),
         repeat()
     );
     this.pollSubscriptions.add(concat(firstRequest$, polling$).pipe(
         retryWhen(errors$ => {
             return errors$.pipe(
                  scan(
                      ({ errorCount, error }, err) => {
                          return { errorCount: errorCount + 1, error: err };
                      },
                      { errorCount: 0, error: null }
                  ),
                  switchMap(({ errorCount, error }) => {
                      if (errorCount >= 3) {
                           throw error;
                      }
                      return observableTimer(3000, null);
                  })
              );
         }),
     ).pipe(tap(updateStatus), takeWhile(data => pollWhileCondition(data))).subscribe());
   }

   stopPolling(): void {
       this.pollSubscriptions.unsubscribe();
   }
```